# Put Request From Index Page In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a site that has a bunch of photos and under each photo is a button that says Upvote. I want that button to submit a PUT request that updates a field in a database. I currently have this code:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
    <% form_for (@user) do |f| %>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Upvote">
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want it to when a user clicks the upvote button it calls the PUT request, updates the value and than redirects to the same page. I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your code is wrong: replace `form_for(@user)` with `form_for(user)`

Second, since the `user` object already exists, it will default to `PUT`. So you've nothing to do.

Comment: I did this and it stopped giving me errors. The only issue is that no button appears for the "submit" command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upvote a user (not the picture?) then put this in your user_controller.rb file:

```
def upvote
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
  @user.upvote
end
```

In your app/models/user.rb

```
def upvote
  self.votes += 1
  self.save
end
```

In your config/routes.rb

```
resources :user do
  put :upvote
end
```

Not tested but should give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have already implemented the code to actually upvote the image (I have user listed simply because I used rails scaffolding). I'm just trying to find a way to call the method from the index page.